# symfony5 - error 500 page instead form error in twig

Tags: php, symfony

I set up a register form using the form builder.

Problem is Symfony throw an InvalidArgumentException page with message`Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "user_name".`

Of course `setUserName` in User entity define `user_name`  type hinted as string but I added constraint `NotBlank` in my form builder. I expected an error inside twig like 'this field can't be empty'.

**EDIT :**
After commenting somme property it appears that this behavior occurs on all of my form fields.

Why errors are not showing up into my twig template ? I've already implements this flow in Symfony 4 and it's working like a charm.

Here is the builder

```php
<?php

namespace App\Form\Type;

use App\Entity\Department;
use App\Entity\Level;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\PasswordType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Length;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Regex;

class InscriptionType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * EntityManagerInterface
     *
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * Build the register form
     *
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     * @return void
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('user_name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Nom',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'Doe'
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 3,
                        'minMessage' => 'Doit comporter 2 caractères ou plus',
                    ]),
                    new Regex([
                        'pattern' => '/^[\wéèêàäâçïöôîûüù\' \-]+$/',
                        'message' => 'La chaîne comporte des caractères non autorisés',
                    ]),
                    new NotBlank()
                ]
            ])
            ->add('user_firstname', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Prénom',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'John'
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 3,
                        'minMessage' => 'Doit comporter 2 caractères ou plus',
                    ]),
                    new Regex([
                        'pattern' => '/^[\wéèêàäâçïöôîûüù\' \-]+$/',
                        'message' => 'La chaîne comporte des caractères non autorisés',
                    ]),
                    new NotBlank()
                ],
            ])
            ->add('user_birthdate', DateType::class, [
                'label' => 'Date de naissance',
                'placeholder' => [
                    'year' => 'Année',
                    'month' => 'Mois',
                    'day' => 'Jours',
                ],
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'input' => 'array',
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank()
                ],
            ])
            ->add('email', EmailType::class, [
                'label' => 'Adresse email',
                'attr' => [
                    'placeholder' => 'john.doe@exemple.com'
                ],
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('user_department', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'Département',
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez un departement',
                'choices' => $this->getDepartmentList(),
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('user_level', ChoiceType::class, [
                'label' => 'Niveau',
                'placeholder' => 'Sélectionnez votre niveau',
                'choices' => $this->getLevelList(),
                'constraints' => [
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('user_description', TextareaType::class, [
                'label' => 'Description',
                'constraints' => [
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 3,
                        'minMessage' => 'Doit comporter 2 caractères ou plus',
                    ]),
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('password', PasswordType::class, [
                'label' => 'Mot de passe',
                'constraints' => [
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 3,
                        'minMessage' => 'Doit comporter 2 caractères ou plus',
                    ]),
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('confirm_password', PasswordType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'label' => 'Confirmation',
                'constraints' => [
                    new Length([
                        'min' => 3,
                        'minMessage' => 'Doit comporter 2 caractères ou plus',
                    ]),
                    new NotBlank(),
                ],
            ])
            ->add('submit', SubmitType::class, [
                'label' => 'Valider',
            ]);

        /* TO DO IMPLEMENTER CAPTCHA */
        /*
    if ($_ENV['GOOGLE_RECAPTCHA_ACTIVE'] === 'true') {
    $builder->add('CaptchaDmd', HiddenType::class,[
    'label' => 'Captcha',
    'mapped' => false, // le captcha n'est pas une propriete existante dans l'entite demandePass, on indique que on ne doit pas la mapper
    'error_bubbling' => false,
    'constraints' => [
    new NotBlank([
    'message' => $this->translator->trans('LibBlankCaptcha')
    ])
    ]
    ]);
    }
     */
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve department list
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function getDepartmentList()
    {
        $repo = $this->em->getRepository(Department::class);
        $departments = [];

        $departmentList = $repo->findAll();

        foreach ($departmentList as $department) {
            # $country est une instance de App\Entity\LangueInternational
            $libelle = $department->getDepartmentNom() . ' (' . $department->getDepartementCode() . ')';
            $valeur = $department->getId();

            $departments[$libelle] = $valeur;
        }

        return $departments;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve level list
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function getLevelList()
    {
        $repo = $this->em->getRepository(Level::class);
        $levels = [];

        $levelList = $repo->findAll();

        foreach ($levelList as $level) {
            # $country est une instance de App\Entity\LangueInternational
            $libelle = ucfirst($level->getLevelName());
            $valeur = $level->getId();

            $levels[$libelle] = $valeur;
        }

        return $levels;
    }

}
```

User entity

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $user_name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $user_firstname;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date")
     */
    private $user_birthdate;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $user_region;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $user_department;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text")
     */
    private $user_description;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $user_level;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->password;
    }

    public function setPassword(string $password): self
    {
        $this->password = $password;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed when using the "bcrypt" algorithm in security.yaml
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }

    public function setUserName(string $user_name): self
    {
        $this->user_name = $user_name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserFirstname(): ?string
    {
        return $this->user_firstname;
    }

    public function setUserFirstname(string $user_firstname): self
    {
        $this->user_firstname = $user_firstname;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserBirthdate(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->user_birthdate;
    }

    public function setUserBirthdate(\DateTimeInterface $user_birthdate): self
    {
        $this->user_birthdate = $user_birthdate;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserRegion(): ?int
    {
        return $this->user_region;
    }

    public function setUserRegion(int $user_region): self
    {
        $this->user_region = $user_region;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserDepartment(): ?int
    {
        return $this->user_department;
    }

    public function setUserDepartment(int $user_department): self
    {
        $this->user_department = $user_department;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->user_description;
    }

    public function setUserDescription(string $user_description): self
    {
        $this->user_description = $user_description;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUserLevel(): ?int
    {
        return $this->user_level;
    }

    public function setUserLevel(int $user_level): self
    {
        $this->user_level = $user_level;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Template

```html
{{ form_start(inscriptionForm, {'attr': {'novalidate' : 'novalidate'}}) }}
      {{ form_errors(inscriptionForm) }}
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{ form_label(inscriptionForm.user_name) }}
          {{ form_widget(inscriptionForm.user_name) }}
          {{ form_errors(inscriptionForm.user_name) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{ form_label(inscriptionForm.user_firstname) }}
          {{ form_widget(inscriptionForm.user_firstname) }}
          {{ form_errors(inscriptionForm.user_firstname) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{ form_label(inscriptionForm.email) }}
          {{ form_widget(inscriptionForm.email) }}
          {{ form_errors(inscriptionForm.email) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{ form_label(inscriptionForm.user_birthdate) }}
          {{ form_widget(inscriptionForm.user_birthdate) }}
          {{ form_errors(inscriptionForm.user_birthdate) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{ form_label(inscriptionForm.password) }}
          {{ form_widget(inscriptionForm.password) }}
          {{ form_errors(inscriptionForm.password) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{ form_label(inscriptionForm.confirm_password) }}
          {{ form_widget(inscriptionForm.confirm_password) }}
          {{ form_errors(inscriptionForm.confirm_password) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{ form_label(inscriptionForm.user_level) }}
          {{ form_widget(inscriptionForm.user_level) }}
          {{ form_errors(inscriptionForm.user_level) }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{ form_label(inscriptionForm.user_description) }}
          {{ form_widget(inscriptionForm.user_description) }}
          {{ form_errors(inscriptionForm.user_description) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{ form_label(inscriptionForm.user_department) }}
          {{ form_widget(inscriptionForm.user_department) }}
          {{ form_errors(inscriptionForm.user_department) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          {{ form_widget(inscriptionForm.submit) }}
        </div>
      </div>
      
      {{ form_end(inscriptionForm) }}
```

And controller which handle form submission

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Form\Type\InscriptionType;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class InscriptionController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/inscription", name="inscription")
     */
    public function inscriptionAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = new User();
        
        // Creation du formulaire d'inscription
        $inscriptionForm = $this->createForm(InscriptionType::class, $user);

        // Si requete en POST et formulaire soumit
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
          error_log('Formulaire inscription soumis');

          // On indique au formulaire de prendre en charge le contenu de la requete
          // Il va mapper les different champs soumis avec le contenu de l entite $user
          $inscriptionForm->handleRequest($request);

          if ($inscriptionForm->isSubmitted() && $inscriptionForm->isValid()) {
            error_log("Formulaire inscription ok, sauvegarde de l'inscription");
          }
        }

        // Affichage
        return $this->render('inscription.html.twig', array(
          'inscriptionForm' => $inscriptionForm->createView(),
          'errors' => (isset($errors) ? $errors : ''),
      ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your InscriptionType plz ?

Comment: already in original post at first piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the `RequestHandler` processes the request it's transforming empty values into `null` and since your fields are not nullable the binding is failing. You can set [`empty_data`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#empty-data) to the empty string (`'empty_data' => '',`) to work around that.

As for the birthdate, you could set todays date, but that would result in bogus data. I'd rather make the field optional, to be honest.

Looking into the entity, none of your setters accept null values. That's another way of fixing your issue, set them all to accept `null`. For instance, change the `birthday` setter to:

```
public function setUserBirthdate(?\DateTimeInterface $user_birthdate): self
```

Then the form will trigger the validation constraint. Be aware that other contexts that doesn't use forms could leave your entity in an invalid state, you might want to consider tightening the schema to avoid inconsistent data, move the constraints to the entity so you can trigger entity validation or use DTOs.

Comment: that's the trick !! thanks. Yeah personaly I would have make it optionnal but it's required for the project.

Comment: @akio I've expanded the answer, I think that's a better solution.

Comment: That's a great explanation. what do you mean by `tightening the schema to avoid inconsistent data` ?

Comment: I tried to move constraint to the entity using this https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html without success...

Comment: @akio Just going over your [`@Column`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/annotations-reference.html#column) definitions and make sure that they are not nullable (the default), if you are accepting null values in the setters to avoid invalid data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should not use getUsername return you email

```
public function getUsername(): string
{
    return (string) $this->email;
}
```

And you setter of setUserName set $this->user_name, not the same as email.

```
public function setUserName(string $user_name): self
{
    $this->user_name = $user_name;

    return $this;
}
```

the function getUsername is set in UserInterface.

Comment: Entity was made using symfony CLI.. email is the unique property to identify user

Comment: The username can be any of other string properties not only the email.